# Eclipse GEF on Mac Snow Leopard

Tags: eclipse, osx-snow-leopard, eclipse-gef

I've been in upgrade mode this month and upgraded my Mac to Snow Leopard.  I've developed a good sized Eclipse RCP which uses GEF.

I upgraded Eclipse on my Mac to 3.5.1-x86_64, latest XCode, etc.

Eclipse 3.5.1 works well; however, when install GEF-3.5.1, the SWT plugin doesn't seem to load properly.  I do see the GEF n Draw2D plugins in the Target Platform listing, but all of my plugins that use SWT now fail to compile. (SWT appears in the Target Platform listing).

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I also had trouble with SWT on Snow Leopard. SWT shipped with Eclipse seems to be 32 bit only while OS X is 64 bit. You can force eclipse to run in 32 bit mode with the VM argument -d32.

During development you can add this switch to the VM arguments field in the Arguments tab in your Run/Debug-Configuration.

For your product add it to your eclipse.ini (not tested yet).